# Как сохранить значения input'а после перезагрузки

Tags: html

```
Длинна пароля<input type="tel" placeholder="" value=""  id="passHeight" maxlength="2" onclick="this.select();" required pattern="[0-9]{,3}" style="display: inline-block;">
```

чтобы при изменении значения после перезагрузки оно осталось

Comment: ` localStorage` - используй...  Или база данных нужна...  Все зависит от потребностей и желаемого конечного результата

Comment: можете это сделать либо php либо js-oм  есть такая штука Кукис

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам сказали, localStorage.
Но он только работает на протоколе https

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBOzqv

Этот сниппет не будет работать тут, для проверки результата зайдите на ссылку codepen

```js
document.getElementById("passHeight").value = localStorage.getItem('fieldDeeta');
function handleInput()
{
  localStorage.setItem('fieldDeeta', document.getElementById("passHeight").value);
}
```

```html
Длинна пароля<input type="tel" placeholder="" value=""  id="passHeight" maxlength="2" onclick="this.select();" required pattern="[0-9]{,3}" style="display: inline-block;" oninput="handleInput()">
```